# Можно ли переписать этот скрипт более компактно, универсально?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".button1").click(function() {
    $(".imgEx1").addClass("active");
    $(".imgEx2").removeClass("active");
    $(".imgEx3").removeClass("active");
  });
  $(".button2").click(function() {
    $(".imgEx1").removeClass("active");
    $(".imgEx2").addClass("active");
    $(".imgEx3").removeClass("active");
  });
  $(".button3").click(function() {
    $(".imgEx1").removeClass("active");
    $(".imgEx2").removeClass("active");
    $(".imgEx3").addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="imgEx1 active">Лак</p>
<p class="imgEx2">Ваниль</p>
<p class="imgEx3">Мёд</p>
<p>
  <span class="button1">Лак</span>
  <span class="button2">Ваниль</span>
  <span class="button3">Мёд</span>
</p>
```

Comment: А он не правильно написан?

Comment: Не, ну он правильный, в смысле работает )), но у меня 99% ощущение, что парень умнее, сделал бы его (скрипт этот) компактнее ))

Comment: @jujujus, добавьте в вопрос вашу html разметку.

Comment: +1 исходя из `html` можно сделать вывод

Comment: Сейчас вы плодите классы и делаете скрипт мало универсальным. А если у Вас будет двадцать кнопок? А если сто? Сделайте один обработчик на общий класс, какой-нибудь `.toggle_active_button` и указывайте конкретную картинку через `data-*` атрибут и заведите общий класс для ваших `imgEx`, что бы не перебирать их все вручную.

Comment: Да-да, согласен )) Это щас у меня всего-то три картинки, а если их 15?! Вот я и интересуюсь... Сам я не знал как это сделать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    // Убираем класс со всех
    $(".imgEx").removeClass("active")
      // Выставляем нужному
      .filter(".imgEx" + $(this).data("idx")).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="imgEx imgEx1 active">Лак</p>
<p class="imgEx imgEx2">Ваниль</p>
<p class="imgEx imgEx3">Мёд</p>
<p>
  <span class="button" data-idx="1">Лак</span>
  <span class="button" data-idx="2">Ваниль</span>
  <span class="button" data-idx="3">Мёд</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Классно уложили )

Answer (score 4):

Я так понял надо как то сократить код.

Будет работать при "правильной" разметке.

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.img').eq($(this).index('.button')).addClass('active')
    .siblings('.img').removeClass('active')
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgs">
  <p class="img imgEx1 active">Лак</p>
  <p class="img imgEx2">Ваниль</p>
  <p class="img imgEx3">Мёд</p>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <span class="button button1">Лак</span>
  <span class="button button2">Ваниль</span>
  <span class="button button3">Мёд</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Шаг влево, шаг вправо в разметке - расстрел на месте.

Comment: @AlexKrass а что вы предлагаете? На дата параметрах все писать или ООП, тьфу, тьфу?

Comment: Автор, я бы еще unbind("click") добавил бы

Comment: @DaemonHK да, если пишите не под конкретную разметку, то на дата параметрах и классах. В противном случае верстальщик может скопытиться, фиксируя разметку в нужные блоки.

Comment: @DaemonHK .unbind() == deprecated в новых версиях заменен на .off() а что бы его использовать надо запускать ивент через .on() да и пример приведенный не посылает запросы на сервер, браузер осилит я думаю, и в данном случае лишние символы появятся))

Comment: @AsanAbildin Вы же в курсе что unbind и ajax и рядом не лежали и никак не связаны друг с другом?